# Logo moving out of menu when adding list

Tags: html, css, list, web

I would like to have my logo inside my menu, and the list in the middle of the page. But only when i make it float right my logo is staying inside my menu... Here's an example: http://gyazo.com/76719bc76c08765cb1f8fee588b3daae

```
<body>
<div id="Wrapper">
<header>
    <div id="Menu">
        <div id="Nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <Div id="logo">
            <img src="Breaking Bad.png" alt="Logo" height="150px">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>   
<div id="Video"><iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Gx7L8FWN80Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div id="News"></div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

```
    body{
    font-family:impact;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color:#4A4247;
    margin:0px;
}
#Wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
}
#Menu{
    color:#09b800;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#151D04;
}
#Nav{
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:table;

}
#Logo{
    clear:right;
    float:left;
}
#Video{
    width:640px;
    height:360px;
    margin-top:20px;
    float:left;
    background-color:black;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#News{
    margin-top:20px;
    width:340px;
    height:360px;
    color:black;
    float:right;
    background-color:black;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#Footer{
    clear: both;
    background-color:black;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: this is incomplete css/html, please create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be usefull:

```
<body>
<style>
   body{
    font-family:impact;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color:#4A4247;
    margin:0px;
}
#Wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
}
#Menu{
    color:#09b800;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#151D04;
}
#Nav ul{
margin:0 auto;

}
#Nav{
width:850px;
margin-left:-75px;
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
    float:left;
}
#Logo{
    clear:right;
    float:left;
    width:150px;
}
#Video{
    width:640px;
    height:360px;
    margin-top:20px;
    float:left;
    background-color:black;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#News{
    margin-top:20px;
    width:340px;
    height:360px;
    color:black;
    float:right;
    background-color:black;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#Footer{
    clear: both;
    background-color:black;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
<div id="Wrapper">
<header>
    <div id="Menu">

        <div id="logo">
            <img src="Breaking Bad.png" alt="Logo" height="150px">
        </div>
        <div id="Nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>   
<div id="Video"><iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Gx7L8FWN80Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div id="News"></div>
<div id="Footer"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

I merge HTML and CSS together,
put float left to both #Nav and #Logo, static width, with negative margin.Read the code and you will notice the trick.